# Why my SwitchListTile not working when I divide into 1 separate Widget?

Tags: flutter

Currently I want to use the SwitchListTile Widget divided into 1 separate Widget to reuse many times, but when I click on it, nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
class SwitchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SwitchScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SwitchScreen> createState() => _SwitchScreenState();
}

class _SwitchScreenState extends State<SwitchScreen> {
  bool check = false;

  Widget _buildSwitchListTile(String title, String description, bool currentValue) {
    return SwitchListTile(
      title: Text(title),
      value: currentValue,
      subtitle: Text(description),
      onChanged:(newValue) {setState(() { currentValue = newValue; });},
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Filters'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text(
              'select',
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                _buildSwitchListTile(
                  'text',
                  'description',
                  check,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to fix it and it was successful, by passing a function to my custom Widget like the code below:

```
class SwitchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SwitchScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SwitchScreen> createState() => _SwitchScreenState();
}

class _SwitchScreenState extends State<SwitchScreen> {
  bool check = false;

  Widget _buildSwitchListTile(String title, String description, bool currentValue, Function(bool) updateValue) {
    return SwitchListTile(
      title: Text(title),
      value: currentValue,
      subtitle: Text(description),
      onChanged: updateValue,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Filters'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text(
              'select',
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                _buildSwitchListTile(
                  'text',
                  'description',
                  check,
                  (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      check = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                 ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

it worked as I wanted, but I don't really know why it did. Can anyone explain it to me please!

Comment: I tried running your first code snippet (the one you say doesn't work), but it seems to work for me. Clicking on the tile changes the value of the switch

Comment: oh, maybe there's something wrong with my question's code, it's true that the same will work. I edited my code and my question is still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SwitchListTile` in new `Stateful class` and pass 3 parameters. Can also add `typedef` callback if you want to know the state of `currentValue` in each `SwitchListTile`.

```
typedef ReturnSingleValue<T> = void Function(T value);

class SwitchClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final bool currentValue;
  final ReturnSingleValue<bool> onChanged;
  const SwitchClass(
      {super.key,
      required this.currentValue,
      required this.title,
      required this.description,
      required this.onChanged});

  @override
  State<SwitchClass> createState() => _SwitchClassState();
}

class _SwitchClassState extends State<SwitchClass> {
  bool currentValue = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    currentValue = widget.currentValue;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SwitchListTile(
      title: Text(widget.title),
      value: currentValue,
      subtitle: Text(widget.description),
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        setState(() {
          currentValue = newValue;
        });
        widget.onChanged(newValue);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And call the `SwitchClass` in parent Widget.

```
ListView(
              children: [
                _buildSwitchListTile(
                  'text',
                  'description',
                  check,
                ),
                _buildSwitchListTile(
                  'text',
                  'descrisption',
                  check,
                ),
                SwitchClass(
                  title: 'text',
                  description: 'desc',
                  currentValue: check,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    print('firstButton $value');
                  },
                ),
                SwitchClass(
                  title: 'text',
                  description: 'desc',
                  currentValue: check,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    print('secondButton $value');
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: This way is really effective to optimize the code, exactly what I want is to only pass 3 parameters, not having to rewrite setState every time I use it. Now I have only one question as to why my first code is not working, I really want to know why.

Comment: @DungxLas For `setState()` the variables must be initialized in the class, like the `bool check` variable. But in `_buildSwitchListTile` the parameter `currentValue ` is being changed which is not initialized like `check` variable.  you will need to create 'currentValue0 ... n` for each `_buildSwitchListTile` function .

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code:

Use this code to use multiple SwitchListTile

```
class Options {
  final String title;
  final String description;
  bool currentValue;
  Options(
      {required this.title,
      required this.description,
      required this.currentValue});
}

class SwitchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SwitchScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SwitchScreen> createState() => _SwitchScreenState();
}

class _SwitchScreenState extends State<SwitchScreen> {
  List<Options> optionsList = [
    Options(
      title: 'text',
      description: 'description',
      currentValue: false,
    ),
  ];

  _buildSwitchListTile(
      {required String title,
      required bool currentValue,
      required String description,
      required onChanged}) {
    return SwitchListTile(
      title: Text(title),
      value: currentValue,
      subtitle: Text(description),
      onChanged: onChanged,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Filters'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: const Text(
              'select',
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: optionsList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return _buildSwitchListTile(
                  title: optionsList[index].title,
                  description: optionsList[index].description,
                  currentValue: optionsList[index].currentValue,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        optionsList[index].currentValue = newValue;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Here the `check` value will change all  `_buildSwitchListTille`  calls. cannot reuse.